# Onboard audio not detected Asrock windows 11

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11

Foremost, I do not use headphones that much aside from gaming (and I didn't game in the last months) so the one thing I do not know is when, precisely, this problem started.

I'm sure that until I had Windows 10 installed I could switch between HDMI Nvidia audio and onboard jack headphones audio. Now there is no way of selecting the second one. To be precise, the computer behaves exactly in the same way with headphones in or not.

**My specs:**

Windows 11
MOBO Asrock B460M Pro4
GPU GeForce RTX 2070S
CPU Intel i5-10400

**What I've tried:**

- Device Manager, update drivers: there seems to just not be any device for the headphones, only my screen with NVIDIA High Definition Audio.
- Install the driver from the Asrock website: I download the Realtek installer, open it, and it says "Now reboot", but nothing changed. I have also tried to download it on the Realtek page, the Intel page, and the Microsoft page, but all yield the same outcome.
- Manually install the driver from Device Manager: BSOD as soon as I click on the Realtek driver.
- Remove GPU and use all onboard, video and audio: the onboard video works fine, but still no audio.- Onboard audio in BIOS: I updated the BIOS and checked the onboard audio option. I tried with it "enabled", "auto", or even "disabled" for the sake of it. No change whatsoever.
- Enable audio output in Settings > System > Audio > Audio Settings: there is nothing to enable there, just the NVIDIA monitor.
- Troubleshooting: I run the Windows troubleshooting. When done with the GPU HDMI monitor, it asks me for the beep and I mean I hear it, but only from the monitor, not from the headphones. When done with onboard HDMI (so no audio whatsoever) it asks me to connect my device (but my device, i.e. my headphones, is connected)What I think is happening is that there is no "headphones device" in the device manager, my computer does not recognize it entering. To clarify, I'm not in love with Realtek or anything, I can settle for any way to use my headphones.

Does anyone have any idea of what I could try? I can live with the audio just coming from my monitor, but for late-night gaming, it isn't the best solution.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the driver install via Windows Update? Settings → Windows Update → Advanced Options → Optional Updates → Driver Updates

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, I have - still no luck.